Why my manifold gauge set doesn't have a connector that a mechanic from a youtube channel has?
Connection from a YouTuber mechanic.

The gauge manifold I have.

Do I simply purchase two adapter to connect to my vehicle's high-side and low-side valves? Or Do I need a new manifold gauge set?

Yes you just purchase those connectors and screw them on to your existing hoses.
For example,  I just did a google search for R134a quick connector.  You need to make sure you get the male thread adaptor (brass in this photo) -

There are lots of different quality ones out there to choose from.  I just picked one that had a good photo.
